# Mail plugins for Grails 3.1.8

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using grails 3.1.8 version and want to install mail plugin. Which plugin version is suitable for this grails version?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send mails over SMTP, use [mail plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/mail). There is also a [Mailgun](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails-mailgun) and [Sendgrid](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails-sendgrid) plugins if you use that services. Take a look over [Grails 3 plugins](http://plugins.grails.org/) to find other plugins that may help you.

My personal recommendation is to use [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. I would recommend using the Grails [Mail](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/mail) plugin as it's been used by many of the Grails application and developers. The biggest advantages of using the mail plugin are:

1. Very popular Grails plugin used by many developers
2. Uses javax-mail API library for sending emails
3. Test coverage
4. Supports all or any kind of mail service providers (like SendGrid, Amazon, Google, Mailgun etc) so you don't have to modify your code if you switch to different mail provider, just changing the configurations is sufficient
5. Out of the box support for another famous Grails plugin i.e. [asynchronous-mail](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/asynchronous-mail) which allows you to store outgoing email in DB for sending them asynchronously.